# groovy get simple date like "03/17/2011" into a Date class

Tags: groovy

I looked at `Date` and `GregorianCalendar`, and it seems pretty tedious to convert something like "**03/17/2011**" into a `Date` object, so that it can be compared with other date objects (also built from these date strings).

Can you give some guidance/direction please?

Comment: For future reference: http://www.groovyexamples.org/tag/date/

I have found that site very handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def d = Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy", "01/01/2011")
```